# R lm: Create regressions dynamically

Tags: r

I have a set of dependent variables `y1, y2, ...`., a set of independent variables `x1,x2,...`, and a set of controls `d1,d2,...`. These are all inside a `data.table`, lets call it `data`.

I need to do something along the lines of

```
out1 <- lm(y1 ~ x1, data=data)
out2 <- lm(y1 ~ x1 + d1 + d2, data=data)
....
```

This is of course not very nice, so I was thinking about writing a list containing all these regressions, and than just iterate through that. Something along the lines of

```
myRegressions <- list('out1' = y1 ~ x1, 'out2' = y1 ~ x1 + d1 + d2)
output <- NULL
for (reg in myRegressions)
{
    output[reg] <- lm(myRegressions[[reg]])
}
```

This of course won't work: I cannot construct the list as the syntax is invalid outside of `lm()`. What's a good approach here instead?

Comment: Give some quick sample data for us to play with.

Comment: formulas can be quoted inside a `lm` call. Try `list('out1' = "y1 ~ x1")`

Comment: @scoa Awesome. Any way I could extend that to allow manipulations on the fly, such as `log(y1) ~ s1`? In any way, you can post this as an answer.

Comment: Nevermind, even `"log(y1) ~ x1"` works in the string form. Awesome!

Comment: look at `?reformulate` and search for `[r] reformulate` on SO ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formulas can be quoted :

```
myReg <- list('out1' = "mpg ~ cyl")
lm(myReg[[1]],data=mtcars)

Call:
lm(formula = myReg[[1]], data = mtcars)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)          cyl  
     37.885       -2.876
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the built in `anscombe` data frame try this:

```
formulas = list(y1 ~ x1, y2 ~ x2)
lapply(formulas, function(fo) do.call("lm", list(fo, data = quote(anscombe))))
```

giving:

```
[[1]]

Call:
lm(formula = y1 ~ x1, data = anscombe)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)           x1  
     3.0001       0.5001  


[[2]]

Call:
lm(formula = y2 ~ x2, data = anscombe)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)           x2  
      3.001        0.500
```

**Note** that the `Call:` portion of the output is accurately produced which will be useful if there are many components to the output list.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `paste0` and `as.formula` to generate formulas and then simply put them into lm(), e. g.

```
regressors <- c("x1", "x1 + x2", "x1 + x2 + x3")


for (i in 1:length(regressors)) {

  print(as.formula(paste0("y1", "~", regressors[i])))
}
```

This gives you the formulas (printed). Just store them in a list and iterate over that list with lapply like

```
lapply(stored_formulas, function(x) { lm(x, data=yourData) })
```